# How to remove duplicate elements from random array I generated?

Tags: c, arrays

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char a[200], b = 0;
    int x;
    x = 100 + rand() % 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        a[i] = 'a' + rand() % 26;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (b % 10 == 0) { 
            printf("\n%c ", a[i]); 
            b = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("%c ", a[i]);
        }
        b++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Purpose is that I should generate random array of letters from 'a' to 'z' (which I've managed to do) and after that print new array without elements that repeat in first array. I've tried implementing code from [here](http://www.studytonight.com/c/remove-duplicate-element-program.php) for removing duplicate elements but it didn't worked in my code.

Comment: Use shuffle to generate an array that contains numbers from 1 to 200 in random order.

Comment: @Arkadiy can't, we haven't learned that yet in class...

Comment: @Sven B  The program has undefined behavior because the value of the variable x set like x = 100 + rand() % 200; can exceed  the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to loop over the array and copy each element to a new array, *but* first check that the value doesn't already exist in the new array.

Comment: Simple and square

Comment: Simple and "squared" 

Comment: It's simple but not very effective.

Answer (score 0):

An `O(n)` solution, assuming your array contains only letters *a* to *z*, consists of creating another small array of 26 integers initialized to zeroes, `exist[26]`, then for each letter from the the main array,

- if `exist[letter - 'a'] > 0` don't print it
- otherwise print it and increment `exist[letter - 'a']`

for instance,

```
int exist[26] = { 0 };

for(int i=0 ; i<x ; i++) {
   if (exist[a[i] - 'a'] == 0) {
      exist[a[i] - 'a']++;
      printf("%c ", a[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the program has undefined behavior due to the statement

```
x = 100 + rand() % 200;
```

because the calculated value of the variable `x` can exceed the size of the array.

I think you mean

```
x = 1 + rand() % 200;
   ^^^
```

Also it is desirable to call the standard function `srand` to get different random sequences when the program runs.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N   200

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N];
    size_t n;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    n = 1 + rand() % N;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        s[i] = 'a' + rand() % ( 'z' - 'a'  + 1 ); 
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        putchar( s[i] );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 10 == 0 || i + 1 == n ) putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n');

    size_t m = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < m && s[j] != s[i] ) j++;

        if ( j == m )
        {
            if ( m != i ) s[m] = s[i];
            ++m;
        }
    }

    n = m;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        putchar( s[i] );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 10 == 0 || i + 1 == n ) putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be like

```
bimiwgnkew
tphzfidwmn
yqoyoxbbxd
kalxljfyvj
upzdoglrez
edsubgsfjr
kvrvscgadb
lxsmdhuoaz

bimwgnketp
hzfdyqoxal
jvursc
```